# Facebook auth works fine on localhost but from my host it wont return user info

Tags: facebook, localhost, cakephp-2.0, facebook-canvas

I am trying to use the Facebook plugin for cakephp written by webtechnick in a canvas app on facebook.

It works fine when my app points to localhost, and I can see all the info about myself using the api('/me') call.

But on my dreamhost server /me returns null, from the same browser, and localhost is still showing /me fine. Other api calls work fine as well, the app id and secret are correct, and I have tried increasing the CURL timeout settings in the sdk.

Are there any settings within the facebook app settings which would always allow localhost, but require more details about the url of my app? I can't see any that seem relevant, and I can't find any other support queries of a similar nature.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the "website" address in the facebook developer settings for your app to point to your updated domain address?

Comment: I've tried a few things. My canvas app points to facebook.mydomain.com, although I want to enable auth on mydomain.com at some point in the future. I've tried both facebook.mydomain.com and mydomain.com in the webesite address, as well as no address, and each one gives me the same... no account info with /me

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the appID and appSecret were wrong - I had inadvertantly copied another config onto the live site.

Hope this helps others in the future!